# How to select just one record for each vehicle in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I ran into a confusing situation here... have a table in mysql which looks like this:

```
                    ----locations----
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  |    time    |    lat    |    lon     | vehicle_id|
|   1  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     1     |
|   2  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     1     |
|   3  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     2     |
|   4  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     2     |
|   5  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     4     |
|   6  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     3     |
|   7  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     2     |
|   8  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     3     |
|   9  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     3     |
|  10  | 1513865119 |13.0398796 | 77.6242876 |     1     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

i am trying to get last known location for each vehicle_id

Here is what i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `locations` ORDER BY id DESC limit 1
```

but the above code returns just one vehicle.

I need to retrive all the vehicles similarly, so how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2):

This would seem to be the query you want:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM locations t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT vehicle_id, MAX(time) AS max_time
    FROM locations
    GROUP BY vehicle_id
) t2
    ON t1.vehicle_id = t2.vehicle_id AND
       t1.time = t2.max_time;
```

This joins your `locations` table to a subquery which finds the most recent record for each vehicle.  I used "seems" above because your sample data, perhaps coincidentally, shows the same exact time for every vehicle.  Of course, for my answer to be meaningful you would need to have greater `time` values for the most recent record per vehicle.

Comment: Note that this query will return multiple records t1.* for the vehicle_id when the MAX(time) is the same for the grouped vehicle_id

Comment: You are amazing! yes the real data has greater  values for time and the join worked like magic! thank you!!

Comment: @RaymondNijlandk Yes, you're right.  But in general I'd rather get all ties back.  MySQL may soon support analytic functions in the near future so we may have more options then.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM locations ORDER BY id
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function you are using DISTINCT as a function.

Comment: Should be `Distinct *`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel as your tag

```
 $loc = Location::select('id', 'lat', 'lon', 'vehicle_id', DB::RAW('max(time) as "time"'))                                   
                            ->groupBy('vehicle_id')
// optional to orderby time ->orderBy('time', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
```